# How can I prevent geom_text from overlapping and make this graph much more displayable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried check_overlap but it just removes the points that are overlapping which I do not want. I've tried messing with hjust and size in geom_text() and while it did help, it's not quite how I want it.

```
ggmap(hawk_map_105936) + 
                  geom_line(aes(x = long, y = lat),
                            color = "gold", hawks_105936) +
                  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, color = factor(speed)),
                             alpha = 1, hawks_105936) +
                  geom_text(aes(x = long, y = lat, label = factor(height)), 
                            alpha = .8, size = 3, hjust = 1.3, hawks_105936) + 
                  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-121.598, -121.578), expand = c(0, 0)) +
                  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(38.755, 38.769), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Here is my plot: The geom_text represents height, while geom_point represents speed and lastly, geom_line represents longitude and latitude. I decided to go about representing my data this way but I'm open to other ideas!

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you give some reproducible data? Also fake but similar to your data are ok.

Comment: Have a look at the `ggrepel` package.

Comment: THANK YOU! I LOVE GGREPEL NOW!